# Synchronize multiple value retrievals in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `3` inputs in the the DOM with id `a`, `b`, and `c` - containing numbers - and a javascript function:

```
function func(a,b,c)
{
    console.log(a+b+c);
}
```

I want to call `func` when any of these `3` inputs refreshes, by taking the value of the two others. For the moment, I am proceding this way:

```
<script>

function func(a,b,c)
{
    console.log(a+b+c));
}

$(function(){

    $('#a').on('change', function(){
        func(this.value, $('#b').val(), $('#c').val())
    });

    $('#b').on('change', function(){
        func($('#a').val(), this.value, $('#c').val())
    });

    $('#c').on('change', function(){
        func($('#a').val(), $('#b').val(), this.value)
    });

});

</script>
```

But this appraoch does not seem elegant, particularly if there is a lot of inputs (we could imagine 2 or 3 more inputs with ids `d`, `e` ..). Would there be a more concise approach in such case?

Comment: Like this (with sorting): http://jsfiddle.net/ddzhereo/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something simple with a CSS class like this:

```
$('.myInputs').on('change', function() {
    var a = $('#a').val();
    var b = $('#b').val();
    var c = $('#c').val();
    func(a, b, c);
});
```

but don't forget to add the class to your inputs

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest:

1. Have a single event handler and a single selector.
2. Pass array of values into a function.

```js
function func(vals) {
  console.log(vals.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0));
}

$(function() {

  var $els = $('#a, #b, #c'); // better to use a common class
  $els.on('change', function() {
    var vals = [];
    $.each($els, function(_, item) {
      vals.push(parseInt(item.value, 10));
    });
    func(vals);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="a">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="b">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="c">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: some comment as for the majority of answers, you are modifying the function. I may have mentionned it since I have a too much func prog approach ...

Answer (score 1):

You can have similar class to every input and calculate it's amount by `$.each`

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.calculate').on('change', function () {
            var result = "";
            $.each($('.calculate'), function () {
                result += $(this).val();
            });
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" name="a" id="a" class="calculate" />
<input type="text" name="b" id="b" class="calculate" />
<input type="text" name="c" id="c" class="calculate" />
<input type="text" name="d" id="d" class="calculate" />
```

Comment: You did not call my function ... which can be a black box and here you split it your code ;)

Comment: hehe right @ColonelBeauvel, i thought this would be easier approach!

Answer (score 1):

By giving similar/unique `class` to required textfield and using `$.each` you can generalize the code as per your requirement.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.mynumberfield').on('change', function(){
    func();
  });
  
  function func()
  {
    var total = 0;
    $('.mynumberfield').each(function(){
      var currVal = $(this).val();

      if($.trim(currVal).length>0 && !isNaN(currVal))
      {
        
        currVal = parseFloat(currVal);
        total +=currVal;
      }
    });
    $("#total").text(total);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
a<input type=text class="mynumberfield" id="a" />
b<input type=text class="mynumberfield" id="b" />
c<input type=text class="mynumberfield" id="c" />
d<input type=text class="mynumberfield" id="d" />
e<input type=text class="mynumberfield" id="e" />
f<input type=text class="mynumberfield" id="f" />
g<input type=text class="mynumberfield" id="g" />

Total:<p id="total"></p>
```

Comment: I would use each in a different approach, to build an array of values and pass it to func. Really wonder why most of the answers are "breaking" the function (sometimes it can't be possible ;) ) ! still +1 for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I find with the above solutions is that they require you in one way or another to keep track of the inputs. This is not scalable. Here is a solution that is more scalable (only requiring you to remember to add a class on the inputs you want included in the calculation/concatenation)

Firstly let's deal with your selector:
1: If say your inputs are of type "text" and all of the fields in your DOM of type "text" are to be considered in your calculation then your selector can be:

```
$("input[type=text]")
```

2: If the above is not the case then set a class on all of the inputs that you want included in the calculation. Then after having added the class (let's say "my_class" for our example) on all of the relevant inputs your selector will be:

```
$(".my_class")
```

So now that we have the selector let's deal with the function:

```
function func($selector)
{
    var allValues = "";

    $selector.each(function(){
        allValues += $(this).value();
    })

    console.log(allValues);
}
```

And if you are not concatenating string values but adding numbers then:

```
function func($selector)
{
    var allValues = 0;

    $selector.each(function(){
        var value = $(this).value().trim();
        allValues += ($(this).value().length>0 && !isNaN(value)) ? parseInt(value) : 0;
    })

    console.log(allValues);
}
```

You would then call this function depending on what your selector is by any of the two
:

```
func($("input[type=text]"));
//OR
func($(".my_class"))
```

Hope I did not miss anything. If I did not understand your question well then say and I will try to adjust my answer accordingly

Comment: no no and no. The function can be extremely generic and you try to remodel it/reinvent the wheel instead of using it! Same comment as for vijayP ;)

Comment: I do not get what you are saying Colonel.

Comment: you are modifying the function, and I do not want this.

Comment: Okay. Let me ask: Are the number of inputs fixed?

Comment: Yes. You can have more inputs (and a function with 5 arguments accordingly in this case).

Comment: Then the solution you approved by Nexxuz is pretty much it. I would suggest you clarify the fact that the number of inputs is always fixed. That is why you have a few people coming up with modified solutions to your question.